# SSL error between Java and LAMP

Tags: java, php, apache, security, ssl

I am running a website on the LAMP stack and our payment gateway have changed their security in some way, so when processing card payments we now come across this:

```
Template : https://www.example.com/ not found!

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

(I've replaced the real address with example.com)

When you click the link that is "not found" the page loads completely fine, no errors, no security issues and our certificates are 100% in all online SSL cert tests and our security rating from SSLLabs is A-, so I can't see what the problem would be?

Is there anything I can do to get around this, or will it be down to our payment gateway to resolve this Java issue?

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like the root CA certificate is missing in your keystore. Check who signed the certificate of your payment provider, and check what is in your jre/lib/security/cacerts file (using keytool -list -keystore .../jre/lib/security/cacerts, substitute the path to your cacerts file here) To fix the problem add the root CA cert to the cacerts keystore.

Comment: I don't have access to the Java whatsoever as that is the payment gateway, we as the merchant are using PHP and our SSL Certs are 100%..

Comment: OK, I thought the exception was thrown on your side. Seems you have to talk to your payment provider asking them why your certificate was rejected. Who signed your certificate?

Comment: Comodo - I've run it through all of the online checkers and they all say it's 100% fine so what more can I do?! :(

Comment: Talk to your payment provider. It's their server that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Just a thought. The certificate you use to talk to the payment provider is not necessary the one used by your web server to authenticate to your customers. Are you sure we are talking about the same certificate?